# Emmet doesnt't work in css Vs Code how do i fix it?

Tags: css, vscode-extensions, emmet

[image][image]
Here is example it's only forking in html and not in css
How to fix this problem?

It's dificult to find information on internet because i am the only one who have this problem

Comment: Emmet (previously Zen Coding) is a set of text editor plugins allowing for high-speed coding in HTML, XML, XSL, and other structured code formats by expanding CSS-like expressions of elements into their corresponding representation. [View tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emmet)

Comment: What are you expecting to get with the `pos` prefix?  You are outside a ruleset.

Comment: @Mark pos is just an example i tried many coomands from here https://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/

Comment: Almost all of those `css` emmet abbreviations are for inside a ruleset ONLY.  They won't work if you are outside a ruleset as your image in the question shows.  Try inside a ruleset.

Comment: @Mark you are right thank you i just started using css and didn't knew it work only inside of a rule set. html work even outside of ruleset

Comment: Great, I added the info as an answer.  I don't know why some people seem to think emmet doesn't work in a css file - it does.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the image shows you are outside of a css ruleset so there are many fewer emmet abbreviations that will work there.  Your image shows what happens with a prefix of `pos` - it suggests things like `:placeholder-shown`, etc. that do appear as part of a css selector.  If you are expecting the rest of the emmet abbreviations, like `bg` for `background-color`, use it IN a ruleset.

---

- There seems to be some confusion from commenters (some since deleted) that emmet does not work in a `css` file - it does and has for some time.